# Invisible Upvote?

Tags: bug, voting, android-app, up-votes

I am on the Andriod SE app on the Galaxy S2 when the problem appeared. I was on this question and upvoted the current posts at that time. For some weird reason, it doesn't show that I upvoted the question but does show that I upvoted the answer as shown:
[image] [image]

As you can see, the upvote button will turn red when clicked, signifying that I did upvote the post. I thought that I might have undone the upvote, causing the red to disappear, so I tried upvoting it again. But at the top, it says "You have already voted on this question". Unknown vote now? Upvote button not red as normal now? Weird... So my question is, why isn't the upvote button red when I upvoted the question?

EDIT: It is not a duplicate because I posted my question 4 months before the duplicate arrived.

Comment: I get the same behaviour on Nexus 5 sometimes. It's probably due to the page not reloading after the up/down vote. If you reload the page (swipe down from the top) you should see the red arrow signifying your vote.

Comment: Sorry but the other question has better wording, and got double the upvotes. Time of posting is not relevant for duplicates. Since the other one has better chance to get the team's attention, leaving my vote.

Comment: Neither questions have enough freehand circles