# 'You have already voted on this answer' appears when neither voting option is filled in

Tags: bug, voting, android-app

So here's what happened: I upvoted the answer (previously at 14) to a score of 15, with the upvote button filled in. I then locked my device. Upon waking it back up, I saw the score was at 15, but the upvote button was no longer filled in. I tried upvoting the answer again, but got this error message:

[image: Error message: You have already voted on this answer]
[*click to enlarge*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z82WS.jpg)

I would assume that the bug has something to do with saving the current state, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Couldn't repro on this question, strangely! But I often see similar bugs (state not saved) on voting & comments.

Comment: In the last twenty minutes or so, I've gotten this problem twice after scrolling down from a question to read answers and scrolling back up afterwards

Comment: This is similar and probably a duplicate of my question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252771/invisible-upvote

Comment: Maybe @PythonMaster. I believe however that the circle was red for a period of time. So... maybe the same bug? Not certain it should be marked as a dupe though...